# Free application for local community?

Tags: calendar, forums, mailing-list

I want to help out in a local community/support group for parents of children with ADHD (Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder). To organize the group we need a place to communicate, organize monthly meetups, schedule some dates and collect information.

So is there a free webapp/service that provides (importance in the given order, at least the first three should be met)

1. free
2. welcome page (static content) for the contact information
3. mailing list where everybody can add himself
4. News with RSS where the organizers can announce next meetup or related events
5. Forum for members to discuss
6. Doodle like functionality
7. Calender to show the events
8. Wiki or some knowledge base solution

I know I could collect free software for forum, mailing list and wiki and set up a server, but it's done on personal time without any budget. Further most members are not technically skilled.

Who knows such an app or an app that might fulfil out needs?
Thank you

Comment: not all functionality is mandatory, it's just my wish list. Sure there are free mailing list applications (items 1-3) like Topica.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that's a lot of functionality.

I think [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) does most of those things, but it's really a tool to help with managing software projects.

I admit it's a crazy idea, and you still would have to set up a server, but you could make it work.

Other than that, I don't see a lot of alternatives to Google's services.

Comment: I know, Google Group does a lot of these things, but it requires people joining to have a gmail adress. Not everyone has one, esp. non power users usually just use the email address of their email provider (DSL company)

Comment: Yep, I can hear you, brother. But I really don't see many other solutions. Have you considered ning.com?

Comment: hm, ning.com looks nice. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a free service that looks reasonable for my needs listed in the question: http://www.mixxt.net/ It offers your own free social network including

- mail all members functionality,
- events,
- news,
- forum,
- wiki,
- blogs,
- pictures,
- private messaging
- and much more, in fact anything you could think of.

The free version just displays some mixxt adverts and does allow only a small number of extra widgets, but unlimited members and base functionality is free.